# Question on Infinte Loop in C++

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

This is kind of a curiosity.

I'm studying C++. I was asked to reproduce an infinite loop, for example one that prints a series of powers:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int powerOfTwo = 1; 

    while (true)
    {
        powerOfTwo *= 2;
        cout << powerOfTwo << endl;
    }
}
```

The result kinda troubled me. With the Python interpreter, for example, I used to get an effective infinite loop printing a power of two each time it iterates (until the IDE would stop for exceeding iteration's limit, of course). With this C++ program instead I get a series of 0. But, if I change this to a finite loop, and that is to say I only change the condition statement to:

```
(powerOfTwo <= 100)
```

the code works well, printing 2, 4, 16, ..., 128.

So my question is: why an infinite loop in C++ works in this way? Why it seems to not evaluate the while body at all?

Edit: I'm using Code::Blocks and compiling with g++.

Comment: I would check what optimization flags are set.

Comment: Did you post the *actual* code here (e.g. via copy and paste), or did you re-type it ?

Comment: works for me. http://ideone.com/tJYZA

Comment: I re-typed it here, but there is no difference from the original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, integers can hold an arbitrary number of digits. C++ does not work this way, its integers only have a limited precision (normally 32 bits, but this depends on the platform). Multiplication by 2 is implemented by bitwise shifting an integer one bit to the left. What is happening is that you initially have only the first bit in the integer set:

```
powerOfTwo = 1; // 0x00000001 = 0b00000000000000000000000000000001
```

After your loop iterates 31 times, the bit will have shifted to the very last position in the integer.

```
powerOfTwo = -2147483648; // 0x80000000 = 0b10000000000000000000000000000000
```

The next multiplication by two, the bit is shifted all the way out of the integer (since it has limited precision), and you end up with zero.

```
powerOfTwo = 0; // 0x00000000 = = 0b00000000000000000000000000000000
```

From then on, you are stuck, since 0 * 2 is always 0. If you watch your program in "slow motion", you would see an initial burst of powers of 2, followed by an infinite loop of zeroes.

In Python, on the other hand, your code would work as expected - Python integers can expand to hold any arbitrary number of digits, so your single set bit will never "shift off the end" of the integer. The number will simply keep expanding so that the bit is never lost, and you will never wrap back around and get trapped at zero.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I didn't even see the first numbers because the output was so fast, so I assumed there were only 0. I also hadn't thought about an integer overflow because for that I wouldn't expect 0 but the limit value of the data-type (which for me is 4 byte). Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

In the infinite loop case you see 0 because the int overflows after 32 iterations to 0 and 0*2 == 0.

Look at the first few lines of output. http://ideone.com/zESrn

`2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432
67108864
134217728
268435456
536870912
1073741824
-2147483648
0
0
0`

Comment: The last value before 0 is -2147483648 since he's using signed numbers.  But the rest is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it prints powers of two until `powerOfTwo` gets overflowed and becomes 0. Then 0*2 = 0 and so on. http://ideone.com/XUuHS

Answer (score 0):

I c++ it has a limited size - so therefore is able to compute even if errror

but the `whole true` makes the case

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you will cause an overflow pretty soon, your int variable won't be able to handle big numbers.

int: 4 bytes signed can handle the range –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

So as @freerider said, your compiler is maybe optimizing the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know all data-type concept in C,C++, so you are declaring powerOfTwo as a integer.
so the range of integer get followed accordingly, if you want an continuous loop you can use char as datatype and by using data conversion you can get infinite loop for you function.

Answer (score 0):

Carefully examine the output of the program. You don't really get an infinite series of zeroes. You get 32 numbers, followed by an infinite series of zeroes.

The thirty-two numbers are the first thirty-two powers of two:

```
1
2
4
8
...
(2 raised to the 30th)
(2 raised to the 31st)
0
0
0
```

The problem is how C represents numbers, as finite quantities. Since your mathematical quantity is no longer representable in the C int, C puts some *other* number in its place. In particular, it puts the true value modulo 2^32. But 2^32 mod 2^32 is zero, so there you are.